# Issues in finding IP addres in my computer and in an online

Tags: ip

Its a small and simple question, But still i didn't get in an online.

I just trying to find out my IP address of my computer.

So with help of online, I just follow `www.whatismyip.com` . so it shows like this "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx".

And when i run `IPCONFIG` in my command prompt, it shows ip address and default gateway.

But it is totally different these ip address[which is got from online and from cmd prompt].

So i just confused,

what is the ip address from "this website `<www.whatismyip.com>` and

what is the ip address from `cmd prompt`.

When i refer in online, there are 2 types of ip address[public and private].

I just confused with these ip addresses. Can anyone please help me to explain me about this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Public IP address is that one which allows that people can access to your web site/app from anywhere on Internet. Private IP is that one which belongs to your Internet local network (your home or another LAN).

Comment: Okay thanks.. and when read about public ip address, i got following information "Most Internet users will only have a dynamic IP assigned to their computer which goes off when the computer is disconnected from the Internet. Thus when it is re-connected it gets a new IP.".. so that, when i disconnect and re-connect the internet, the public ip address remains the same.. may i know how?

Comment: Depends of type of Internet service you're using. You can pick for the option you think is the best. 
Dynamic option: your server will change its IP for your users visiting the web site.
Static option: The opposite.

Comment: Okay, may i know, how to identify my internet service whether its static or dynamic?

Comment: Go to http://www.whatsmyip.org/; there you'll see your IP and dynamic feature or static.